# Is acceleration in mutual attraction of two particle system is uniform

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, acceleration

The gravitational force on a body due to another body is $\frac{Gmm'}{R^2}$ where the mass of the respective bodies are $m$ and $m'$

So the acceleration of one body (say mass $m$)  be $\frac{F}{m}$ which is $\frac{Gm'}{R^2}$. Therefore, acceleration is function of separation of the two bodies meaning acceleration keeps on  increasing as separation becomes smaller and smaller. Which implies *acceleration will be non uniform*? Is that right or am I figure this out incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Consider any sphere which is defined by a distance $R$ from the centre of any of the two masses $m$ and $m'$. At all points on these spheres, the magnitude of the acceleration will be uniform. However, if you consider $R$ to be decreasing then the magnitude of the acceleration will increase for all $r$ < $R'$. For any fixed $R$ you will have constant acceleration. For example, anywhere on the surface of the Earth (that is, all points defined by $r = R_{earth}$), you will have a constant acceleration of about $9.8 m/s^2$ (ignoring differences in Earth's density from point-to-point and inertial forces).

Answer (score 0):

well we can think of this very easily if we switch our focus towards the gravitational field ($\vec{E_{g}}$) instead of the force ; let us also say that one of our particles is fixed ; then we can see that the field due to the fixed mass is not constant in space and increases as the radial distance decreases ; hence the acceleration of the moving body increases as force on it increases ! hence, acceleration is not constant for sure

[image]

but you can see that in the cartesian system the direction of the field is different ; hence the field is non-uniform but if we release the moving particle from a point it is bound to move in the radial direction hence it's acceleration has a varying magnitude but a constant direction !